# iphone:access UIButton instance by Tag

Tags: iphone, tags

I placed 6 UIButton on nib, I don't want to create 6 variables for each of button, is there any way to access buttons by their Tag or something else?

I found a method viewWithTag, but seems it is used for NSView.

THX~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created them by Interface Builder, you must go to IB and assign a unique tag to each button (1, 2, ...) and inside your code you can refer to them by `UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1]`, `UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:2]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't need to create "variables" for control elements, except you want to manipulate them during runtime. You can just create your methods and link them to specific actions (push up inside) of the UIButtons. The methods will be called without the need of instance variables of the UIButtons.

Otherwise, if you want to set the buttons enabled/disabled or manipulate any other attributes, you **have** to create variables for them. I don't see why you should do this with tags, because creating pointers to the UIButton instances requires only 2 lines of code (and one to synthesize them all).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm doing a programe to control 6 buttons by codes. So, it needs me create an UIButton Array to store/point to the instance of the buttons. I may need change the button text/images by codes.

Comment: Then simply add the variables with IBOutlet UIButton *button1; make the property with @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1; and so on and synthesize them all in your .m file with @synthesize button1, button2 etc. After that, link your UIButtons to your ViewController. That's so simple and has to be done only once. Don't be that lazy, programming something takes time and lines of code ;-)

Comment: Thx, maybe my description is make you misunderstanding, for my case, I think 2nd answer is what I need. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender{

    NSInteger tag = [sender tag];

    if (tag == 1) {
        NSLog(@"You Pressed 1");
    } else if (tag == 2) {
        NSLog(@"You Pressed 2");
    }

}
```

Now in the the Interface Builder, set the tag to 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        NSLog(@"%d",button.tag);

}
```